# Django get users with userprofiles

Tags: django, profiles

how can I get users with their userprofiles?

I have my own comments app

Model:

```
APPS = (
    (1, 'Game'),
    (2, 'Article'),
    (3, 'CMS'),
    (4, 'User profile'),
)
comment_type = models.IntegerField(choices=APPS,
                                    default=1,
                                    verbose_name="Comment Type")
object_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = False, related_name='user')
```

View:

```
context = {
    ...
    'comments': Comment.objects.filter(comment_type=1, object_id=game_id),
    ...
}
```

UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    signature = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

And my view:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
....
{{ comment.user.profile.signature }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am django rookie. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [.select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) here, as Comment already has a foreign key to User, and User has a foreign key to Profile:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    comment_type=1, object_id=game.id).select_related('user__userprofile')
```

[.prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does a separate lookup for each query. .select_related() grabs everything in one statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have to use no 'user__profile' but 'user__userprofile'.

Comment: Oops, my fault. I will correct the answer to match.